# Can't make Jenkins to work with Git and BitBucket

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

First of all, I want to say I'm newbie to Jenkins. That said, I'm asked, by my company, to study the move of our "home made" build system, based on some powershell scripts, to Jenkins.

Our development server is:

- Windows 7 Pro
- Git
- Source code hosted on BitBucket
- Jenkins (lastest version at the time I'm writing).

I followed a bunch of tutorials to setup git within Jenkins (URL, exe path, SSH key, Jenkins service runs with the right user account, etc) and I guess this is correct, but the output logs are so obscur, I can't really say.

I added to Jenkins a sample project, and needed information to make it build, so the URL is:

```
git@bitbucket.org:<company account>/<repository to build>
```

Branch to get is "`**`".

This script runs for about 10 mn (if I run my Powershell equivalent, it is built in less than 2 mns) and fails, here is the log:

```
Building in workspace D:\jenkins\jobs\#project#\workspace
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:#company#/#project#.git
Cleaning workspace
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe rev-parse --verify HEAD
No valid HEAD. Skipping the resetting
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe clean -fdx
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:#company#/#project#.git
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe --version
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:#company#/#project#.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
FATAL: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:#company#/#project#.git
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from git@bitbucket.org:#company#/#project#.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:623)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:855)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:880)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1252)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:530)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:#company#/#project#.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code -1:
stdout: 
stderr: 
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1325)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$200(CliGitAPIImpl.java:87)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:257)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:621)
    ... 10 more
```

So, I tried to run a command prompt from the project folder and run "by hand" each command I see in this log. And...no trouble, everything works fine.

Finally I'm here asking for some help, I'm a bit lost. Thanks.

**EDIT1** : Added screenshots asked by Quinnly.

**Jenkins GIT settings**
[image: Jenkins GIT settings]

**Example projects settings**
[image: Example projects settings]

**EDIT2**

I've tried to compare the .git data first from my sample project when it is built through my own build system and then from Jenkins.

*The .git/config file*

When built from our own system, this file contains the line:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

And the same from the Jenkins workspace doesn't contain this data. Also, on our own system, this file has a [branch "master"] section with 2 lines "remote" and "merge". From Jenkins, the whole section and its 2 lines are not in the config file.

Comment: Are you editing the repo URL for privacy in the output above ?  git@bitbucket.org:/.git doesn't look like a valid repo URL (as opposed to git@bitbucket.org:accountname/reponame.git, which is the correct format according to the BitBucket documentation)

Comment: Are you running shell commands in your Jenkins job for each command? Or are you using the git plugins within Jenkins.  If you're using the plugin, can you post a screenshot of your settings (with sensitive items blurred) so we can confirm your setup?

Comment: @gareth_bowles yes it was for privacy, but everything seems fine on my side.

Comment: @Quinnlv, no I directly run the GIT plugin. Just posted some screenshot. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. The path to the RSA private key was malformed. Now it works.

Comment: "The path to the RSA private key was malformed."
Please, could you tell us where it was malformed?
How did you deal with it? Don't forget your post is also here to help others than you...

Comment: Happy to help as much as I can. It's pretty old for me now, but I remember it was in some "advanced" properties somewhere. It was not easily visible and I add to reach a second or third level of properties depth to find it.

Comment: I had the same issue. Thanks for sharing this. 
I had to go to the credentials manager, then select the user, and update the private key. I had accidentally pasted the public key instead of the private key.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to bring back the help I received on my own.